# Passing a std::unique_ptr as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++, function, parameters, compiler-errors, unique-ptr

I got a structure and a function like the following:

```
struct MYOVERLAPPED : public OVERLAPPED
{
    //...
};


void func1(std::unique_ptr<MYOVERLAPPED> pBuf)
{
    //...
};
```

I am obtaining a pointer to MYOVERLAPPED which i want to pass to the func1-function.
The problem i encounter is, that no matter what i try i get the following errors :

What i did try already are the following:
Try1:

```
std::unique_ptr<OVERLAPPED> pOver(//....)
HandleAcceptIndication(std::move(pOver));
```

> Error: Error  1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   '_OVERLAPPED **' to 'MYOVERLAPPED *'

Try2:

```
HandleAcceptIndication(new ACCEPT_OVERLAPPED);
```

> Error 1   error C2664: 'HandleAcceptIndication' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'MYOVERLAPPED *' to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

Anyone knows how i can pass this casted pointer of OVERLAPPED to MYOVERLAPPED to the function and why Try2 does not work either since i casually use `std::unique_ptr<MYOVERLAPPED> pO(new MYOVERLAPPED)`  which does work...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While you cannot convert from `std::unique_ptr<base>` to `std::unique_ptr<derived>` directly, it is not too hard to write a cast function that will be *safe* (i.e. not leak the resource under any circumstance, and only succeed if the cast is valid:

```
template <typename Dst, typename Src>
std::unique_ptr<Dst> unique_dynamic_cast( std::unique_ptr<Src>& ptr ) {
    Src * p = ptr.release();                             // [1]
    std::unique_ptr<Dst> r( dynamic_cast<Dst*>(p) );     // [2]
    if ( !r ) {
        ptr.reset( p );                                  // [3]
    }
    return r;                                            // [4]
}
```

The basic idea is that we need to extract the pointer from the `std::unique_ptr` and set it aside in [1]. We cannot try `dynamic_cast` directly, as if that fails, `ptr` would have released ownership, and the memory would be leaked. Then we try and perform the `dynamic_cast` [2] from the local pointer to the requested type of pointer and pass ownership onto the `r` result unique pointer. If the `dynamic_cast` fails, then `r` will be null, and we need to return ownership of the memory to the original `std::unique_ptr` [3], for calling code to decide what to do with it. We then return the *converted* `std::unique_ptr` to the caller in [4].

Comment: wouldnt it be possible do directly dynamic_cast on unique_ptr.get() instead of release?

Comment: @Incubbus: Yes, that is also possible, but you have to make sure that only one `std::unique_ptr` holds ownership of the memory (i.e. if the `dynamic_cast` succeeds, the next thing would be releasing the memory from the original `std::unique_ptr`: `std::unique_ptr<Dst> r( dynamic_cast<Dst*>(ptr.get()) ); if ( r ) ptr.release();`

Comment: but it gives the same error... I asked this question, because i already tried this out... that freaks me out a bit :(... i dont have private inheritance or something like it within the structure so i dont know whats wrong :/

Comment: well... to be exactly it says: Error 1 error C2681: '_OVERLAPPED *' : invalid expression type for dynamic_cast

for std::unique_ptr<ACCEPT_OVERLAPPED> ptr(dynamic_cast<ACCEPT_OVERLAPPED*>(pOverlapped.get()));

Comment: works fine with static cast... cannot use dynamic_cast, because OVERLAPPED has no virtual funcions (as the error description that came up today after i found some bugs, said)...

Comment: If you don't have virtual functions, then there will be no RTTI, and the cast is inherently unsafe. You can then avoid all the trouble and just do: `std::unique_ptr<derived> d( static_cast<derived*>(base_ptr.release()) )`. Not nice, but should work. Alternatively, if you are using this in more than one place, you can hide it behind a template similar to the one in the answer, just simpler, since the cast is guaranteed to *succeed* (for whatever definition of *succeed* you want to use, i.e. it will not detect failure)+

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you're trying to cast the wrong way in the inheritance hierarchy. You're trying to convert from Base* to Derived* implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`unique_ptr<A>` and `unique_ptr<B>` are unrelated types. You can't convert between them unless an implicit conversion exists between `A*` and `B*` (thanks UncleBens), which is not true in this case. Also you should not cast down the inheritance hierarchy with an instance that is not the subclass you are casting to.  In this case, you're trying to cast a `OVERLAPPED` to a `MYOVERLAPPED` which is an invalid cast because an `OVERLAPPED` is not a `MYOVERLAPPED`. That's why you can't convert between the `unique_ptr` types in the first place.

If you are just trying to pass a `unique_ptr` to `func1`, you can do it like this:

```
func1(shared_ptr<MYOVERLAPPED>(new MYOVERLAPPED));
```

Also, by passing a `unique_ptr` to a function, the pointer in the original one gets set to NULL. Consider using references or `shared_ptr`s if you are not creating the `unique_ptr` as a temporary and passing it to the function and you need to use the same instance later.

Comment: Actually implicit conversion between `unique_ptr<A>` and `unique_ptr<B>` exists if there is an implicit conversion between `A*` and `B*`.

Comment: @Uncle ugh, I thought I went through this and couldn't do it. I'll revise my answer...

Comment: But i have to do something like this, because i am checking some variable and casting from OVERLAPPED to MYOVERLAPPED1 or MYOVERLAPPED2 depending on what the indicator says. (what i did before was (MYOVERLAPPED*)pOverlapped - which worked just fine, because pOverlapped points to an MYOVERLAPPED [yes, i know it can only "see" the overlapped part])

so how would you do this? or shall i switch back to native pointers - which isn´t that comfortable

Comment: @Incubbus assuming `OVERLAPPED` destructor is virtual and you have a pointer named `overlappedPtr` of type `OVERLAPPED*` that _really_ points to a `MYOVERLAPPED1`, you can do `func1(unique_ptr<MYOVERLAPPED1>((MYOVERLAPPED1*)overlappedPtr);`